# input() is always producing "None"

Tags: python, python-3.x

Whenever I run the grading program I created,  it works fine but the text "None" keeps showing up and I don't know why. Here's the code:

```
Grade_in=input(print("Enter Your Grade (Only Upper Case):"))
if (Grade_in=='A+') :
    print ("Numeric Grade is 4")
elif (Grade_in=='A'):
    print("Numeric Grade is 4")
elif (Grade_in=='A-'):
    print("Numeric Grade is 4.3")
elif (Grade_in=='B+'):
    print ("Numeric Grade is 3.3")
elif (Grade_in=='B'):
    print ("Numeric Grade is 3")
elif (Grade_in=='B-'):
    print ("Numeric Grade is 2.7")
elif (Grade_in=='C+'):
    print ("Numeric Grade is 2.3")
elif (Grade_in=='C'):
    print ("Numeric Grade is 2")
elif (Grade_in=='C-'):
    print ("Numeric Grade is 1.7")
elif (Grade_in=='D+'):
    print ("Numeric Grade is 1.3")
elif (Grade_in=='D'):
    print ("Numeric Grade is 1")
elif (Grade_in=='D-'):
    print ("Numeric Grade is 0.7")
elif (Grade_in=='F') :
    print ("Numeric Grade is 0")
else :
    print ("Invalid Grade..!")

OUTPUT :
Enter Your Grade (Only Upper Case):
NoneB-
Numeric Grade is 2.7
```

Comment: Remove the `print` function from inside `input` function.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This line:

```
Grade_in=input(print("Enter Your Grade (Only Upper Case):"))
```

should be:

```
Grade_in=input("Enter Your Grade (Only Upper Case):")
```

Your original code is equivalent to this:

```
ret = print("Enter Your Grade (Only Upper Case):")
Grade_in = input(ret)
```

`print` always returns `None`, so `ret` is `None`, so your call to `input` prints out `None`.

You don't need the `print` at all, since `input` already prints out what you pass into it.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the return type of `print()` function :

```
>>> type(print())
=> <class 'NoneType'>
```

So when you say

```
Grade_in=input(print("Enter Your Grade (Only Upper Case):"))
```

`input` takes a string as its argument, which it will **print automatically**. So since your print `statement` executes first, and returns a `None`, which is then printed by the `input` function, hence you have the `None` printed there too.

What you did extra infact was the `print` statement inside the `input` function. Just remove it, and it will work as desired.

```
Grade_in=input("Enter Your Grade (Only Upper Case):")
```

Comment: Add a newline (`\n`).

Answer (score 0):

I know everyone has been saying this, but yes, you should remove the print statement inside the input function. After removing, your code should work. But also, this has happened to me before, and there are a few other ways to solve this kind of problem.

Here is my code:

```
from rich import print
while True:
    command = input(print("[green](CMD)[red]~$"))
```

Whenever I was running that code, the following happened:

```
(CMD)~$
None
```

So I changed the code so instead of a print inside an input, i used a print then an empty input:

```
print("[green](CMD)[red]~$", end=" ")
command = input("")
```

After this, my code worked. If you wanted to put colors into your code, this is how you would do it. That is how you could make your code work.